# Method signature in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, method-signature

I'm trying to understand, how does method signature in Objective-C is look like.

**INTRO:**

At first, lets break misunderstandings about question, what is it, method signature?
Method signature it is something, that helps compiler unambiguously identifies subroutine. 
Am i right? :)

So in the C language signature is roughly equivalent to its prototype definition:
For example, we have function **`int printf( const char *format, ... );`** in stdlib.
Signature of this function is **printf**.
In this case, we can't overload in C language, because compiler can't identify function with different argument types, so people decide to do some tricky thing like this:

```
long int labs (long int n);
int      abs  (int n);
double   fabs (double x);
```

In the C++ language, method signature is class name, method name and method arguments.
So in this language we can overload methods.

**PROBLEM**

I can't get simple answer, what is method signature in Objective-C?!
I'm trying to use my logic...

1)At first, we can't overloading in Objective-C => method arguments is not part of method signature.

2)I tried to compile code with different return value:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (CGFloat)method;
- (NSInteger)method;
@end
```

I got error in this case => return value is not part of method signature.

---

I tested different cases and got the answer, method signature in Objective-C is class name, method type ('+' or '-') and selector.
For example, we have method in class Foo (code below):

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
+ (void)methodWithArgument:(NSInteger)argument;
@end
```

So the signature of this method is **+[Foo methodWithArgument:]**

But then, i look at apple's documentation of NSMethodSignature (http://bit.ly/1tGR8zt)

> An NSMethodSignature object records type information for the **arguments
>   and return value of a method**

Arguments and return value?! Only using arguments and return value, we can unambiguously identify method? It's very strange.

Answer (score 5):

First thing. Who said that compiler can differentiate between 2 methods on the basis or its return type

so

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (CGFloat)method;
- (NSInteger)method;
@end
```

is wrong. Even in C or C++ you cannot overload method on the basis of its return type. Overloading can be performed on the basis of type of argument or number of arguments for a methods or both.

so over loading  can be performed in this way only

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
-(ReturnType)methodNameHere:(int)argument;
-(ReturnType)methodNameHere:(int)argument secondArgumentDescription:(BOOL)anotherArgument;
-(ReturnType)methodNameHere;
```

compiler identifies different methods on the basis for number of arguments and their data type

Answer (score 3):

Method signature is for developers and for runtime,
Not for compiler. (Compiler uses another technique to understand signatures)

Answer (score 2):

you cannot identify methods that have the same name but different return types. If you call it while discarding the return value, which one should be called?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (CGFloat)method;
- (NSInteger)method;
@end

Foo *foo = [Foo new];
[foo method]; // no use for return value here. Which implementation to call?
```